# Laravel task scheduler not working for specified time range

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cron, cron-task

I have a Laravel 5 task which I am scheduling to run between a specified time range every day:

```
$schedule->call(function () {
             // task omitted
        })->daily()->timezone('Europe/London')->between('14:00', '15:00');
```

This does not work, however if I change it to run every minute using `everyMinute();` then it does run successfully:

```
       $schedule->call(function () {     
             // task omitted
        })->everyMinute();
```

My CRON on the server is set to run every half an hour as it's a shared hosting so it can't run for less than half an hour:

```
0,30    *   *   *   *   /usr/local/bin/php -q /home/username/public_html/bookings/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Anyone know why the first cron job: `daily()->timezone('Europe/London')->between('14:00', '15:00');` is not running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a conflicting rule.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling

daily() sets the task to run daily at midnight. 
between() limits the task to only run between certain hours (basically a secondary condition).

So your between rule is going to make it so it never runs since it will be only be run at midnight then it will fail the between condition.

Use `dailyAt('14:00')` instead of `daily()->between()`

Comment: Oh I see, but it won't be guaranteed to run at 14:00 because the CRON job on the server is set to run every half an hour, so it may never be 14:00 when the task runs?

Comment: 0,30 means 14:00 and 14:30 as 0,30 indicates at the 0 minute and 30 minute.